# Cannot Get/ React JS server tutorial

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Im try to do the React JS tutorial and im trying the server in node. I downloaded first, all files in https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/ then I put in folder then I command prompt it. and type npm install then node server.js "Server started: //localhost:3000./

Then when I go to the localhost:3000.is said Cannot Get/ .

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you entering localhost:3000 without a period?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to learn React JS. Please install on the local machine and related module like node JS, etc.

Please have look below link for your review. May be it will help you.

[React JS – Install and Setup](http://www.tutorial-hub.com/tutorial/reactjs/react-js-install-setup/)